# csv-parser, delimiter usage

Tags: node.js, csv-parser

There is a csv file separated by semicolons.

The problem is solved when I replace all semicolons in the file with commas. but I want it to parse the csv file with semicolon.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('public/event-list/event-list.csv')
  .pipe(csv({delimiter: ';'}))
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
  
    res.render('results-page', {
      title: 'Results',
      eventsData:results
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `seperator` instead of `delimiter`

```
csv({separator: ';'})
```